# Formatting a grid-like div in css

Tags: html, css

So I am having some trouble formatting my data into rows of 3, and then have the 4 start at the top of next row. I am also doing this in bootstrap CSS framework.

Please forgive my extremely poor design, but this is what I am talking about:

[Stack won't let me post images, so this is a link to the image. On my github, it's safe](https://github.com/jordmax12/SweetsCompleteASP/blob/master/Design.jpg)

So again, I am trying to have my data (this would be in a foreach loop) organized as such. I have tried a couple things but nothing seems to work.

```
@foreach (var question in Model)
{
    string link = "http://www.stackoverflow.com" + @question.QuestionLink;

    <tr>
        <td class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="media" style="width: 150px; float: left;">
                <a class=" pull-left" href="@link" style="width: auto; height: 72px;">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => question.QuestionTitle)</h4>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is one solution I tried, before doing rows I simply wanted to see if I can organize them in 1 row and then I would move to 2.

This is the result with the current code:

[Stack won't let me post images, so this is a link to the image. On my github, it's safe](https://github.com/jordmax12/SweetsCompleteASP/blob/master/format.png)

Also, I know this is in C#HTML but the html/css part is all the same, so if you don't know about the foreach loop part, or the '@' signs, don't worry about it.

*UPDATE HTML ONLY PART IF CONFUSED*

```
<div class="container">
<tr>
    <td class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="media" style="width: 150px; float: left;">
            <a class=" pull-left" href="link" style="width: auto; height: 72px;">
                <h4 class="media-heading">Title</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems server-side code. Please post the resulting HTML. And CSS.

Comment: what? no this is the html that i am using.

Comment: also the CSS I am using is bootstrap.

Comment: C#HTML is unrelated to the question, and makes it less easy to reproduce. If you post pure HTML, you can use a code snippet in order to see the result live.

Comment: I updated the question with a HTML only part.

Comment: You are using a table row with no parent table. The bootstrap grid system is .container or .container-fluid (no nesting), .row (div,section,article,not table), then the immediate children are col-X-X and they are div, aside, figure, whatever is appropriate and semantic but not table cells or table rows.

Comment: Look at the grid system carefully: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: yeah I am really bad at front-end. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I understand the grid system, kind of, but my problem is that I am trying to have a column and a max number of rows, and then have it start a new column after the max number of rows was hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/a5800uj5/

Not sure if this what you are looking for?
Remember that you can asign amount of columns that one cell should cover with `colspan`.

If you are going to be structured with tables. Used them all the way through with tables, table headers, table rows and table columns.

Comment: Yes that's a huge start, thank you very much. I can write algorithms, but can't figure out correct front-end CSS =\

Comment: role="presentation" on that table http://wps.pearsoned.com/wps/media/objects/8905/9119213/PG11presentationFIX.html